# Handling MvxViewModel::Close when using custom view presenters

Tags: mvvmcross

I am using a custom view presenter in my Windows Store app.

I show a SettingsFlyout and in its SettingsViewModel view-model I have a command bound to a button on the flyout which needs to hide the flyout (SettingsFlyout::Hide()).

For this, I have different options:

- in the SettingsFlyout, I can handle the button click
- in the ICommand in the view-model, send a message from view-model to view
- in the ICommand in the view-model, call `Close(this)`.

  I was trying to implement last one, using Close(this) in the view-model.

  For this, in the custom view presenter I was thinking to handle `ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)` or `Close(IMvxViewModel viewModel)`.

  But I don't see how to get the view instance corresponding to the view-model instance.

  In my case I have the SettingsViewModel instance and I need to get the instance of the displayed SettingsFlyout.

  Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a custom presentation/navigation, so this is left open to the individual app to implement.

Some possible ideas are:

- the Presenter could keep a list of shown Views (and then get their ViewModels by inspecting their `ViewModel` / `DataContext` property) - if doing this, be careful to remove each View from this list when they are closed otherwise this could cause horrible memory leaks.
- the `SettingsFlyout` class could itself just have a `Current` static member - or could call a singleton service which stores the `Current` (if needed this could be archicted into a more general solution - beyond just the SettingsFlyout)
- the Presenter could inspect and search the VisualTree for the appropriate View to close
- the `Closed` mechanism could be a custom event or property fired from your SettingsFlyoutViewModel to your SettingsFlyoutView - instead of using a NavigationHint.

Comment: thanks. last one I mentioned it too. Forgot to mention others which I have already thought about. The #2 looks a bit interesting. What I was hoping was to find some magical built-in feature in Mvvmcross I wasn't aware of :) but thanks again