# I want to understand how to associate a view model with a SettingsFlyout in mvvmcross

Tags: windows-store-apps, inversion-of-control, mvvmcross

I have a Windows Store app using mvvmcross and I am trying to associate a SettingsFlyout, which is created by passing an instance of the view to the SeetingsPane using the ApplicationCommands.Add() method, with a view model in my Core (which is a PCL). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please share what you have tried. Edit your Q and post your code

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173382/handling-mvxviewmodelclose-when-using-custom-view-presenters and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368013/how-do-you-bind-a-viewmodel-to-the-windows-8-settings-pane-in-mvvmcross/16371208#16371208 - both come up when you search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmvvmcross%5D+SettingsFlyout

Comment: Thanks, the second link provides the guidance I was looking for. I did search on those keywords (or something similar), but did not get the results you did. I'm not sure why. I'll try to be more rigorous in my search next time.